# Extjs tagfield disable horizontal grow

Tags: extjs, tags

I tried to set in my app tagfield like this:

```
Ext.define('ExtTagsField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Tag',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {fields: [], data: []}),
    hideTrigger: true,
    createNewOnBlur: true,
});
```

and its look like:

[image]

but when add new tag the width auto update and all the box stretch:

[image]

How can I prevent the tagfield grow horizontal?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try setting the [`maxWidth`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#cfg-maxWidth) of the `tagfield`

Answer (score 0):

You can give it either a width or a maxWidth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxWidth`, according to the docs:

> The maximum width of this Component; must be a valid CSS length value, e.g: 300, 100px, 30%, etc. If set to auto, it will set the width to null meaning it will have its own natural size. Note that this config will not apply if the Component is 'positioned' (absolutely positioned or centered)

So you can try this:

```js
Ext.define('ExtTagsField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Tag',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {fields: [], data: []}),
    hideTrigger: true,
    createNewOnBlur: true,
    maxWidth: 50%,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxWidth` config to stop growing the field. Keeping `width` and `maxWidth` same will avoid the hassle of increase and decrease in the width while selecting the values.

Below is the working example for the same.

```
var shows = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id','show'],
    data: [
        {id: 0, show: 'Battlestar Galactica'},
        {id: 1, show: 'Doctor Who'},
        {id: 2, show: 'Farscape'},
        {id: 3, show: 'Firefly'},
        {id: 4, show: 'Star Trek'},
        {id: 5, show: 'Star Wars: Christmas Special'}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
    height: 200,
    width: 500,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tagfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
        store: shows,
        displayField: 'show',
        valueField: 'id',
        queryMode: 'local',
        filterPickList: true,
        width: 400,
        maxWidth: 400
    }]
});
```